# jQuery live clock with optional 24 or 12 hours

Tags: jquery, html, live, clock

How do you make a jQuery **only** live clock that automatically loads and starts moving, with this structure?:

hour:minute:second

Two columns each separated by semicolons, and also have a universal or not option (e.i. 6'o'clock vs. 18'o'clock). It would have a button next to it that would toggle back and forth saying "change display" or something

Comment: What do you mean by "jQuery only"? You mean with no other JS libraries?

Comment: What do you mean by "live"? And what does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: I didn't want any PHP, basic JavaScript, or something else. Just HTML and the JS library jQuery

Comment: By live I meant as soon as you open the page the clock would start, nuch like an analog clock works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
setInterval(function() {
    var date = new Date();
    $('#clock-wrapper').html(
        date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds()
        );
}, 500);
```

This is a simple example to tell you how it works.

Comment: 1ms interval? Surely 50ms is more than adequate?

Comment: You guys realize a clock increments in seconds and that 1000ms is 1 second, right?

Answer (score 5):

Best Example here -

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
});

function updateClock (){
  var currentTime = new Date ( );
   var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
   var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
   var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );

   // Pad the minutes and seconds with leading zeros, if required
   currentMinutes = ( currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentMinutes;
   currentSeconds = ( currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "" ) + currentSeconds;

   // Choose either "AM" or "PM" as appropriate
   var timeOfDay = ( currentHours < 12 ) ? "AM" : "PM";

   // Convert the hours component to 12-hour format if needed
   currentHours = ( currentHours > 12 ) ? currentHours - 12 : currentHours;

   // Convert an hours component of "0" to "12"
   currentHours = ( currentHours == 0 ) ? 12 : currentHours;

   // Compose the string for display
   var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;
   
   
    $("#clock").html(currentTimeString);    
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock"></div>
```

Source - http://www.sitepoint.com/create-jquery-digital-clock-jquery4u/ 
http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2013/06/digital-clock/

Comment: Just a note - document.ready has to appear after the clock function.

Answer (score 0):

```
        function startTime() { 
         let today = new Date(); let h = today.getHours(); 
         let m = today.getMinutes(); 
         let s = today.getSeconds(); 
         var d = today.getDay(); 
         var day = today.getDay();
         var dayarr =["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thur","Fri","Sat"]; day=dayarr[day]; 
         let ampm = h >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM'; h = h % 12; h = h ? h : 12; // the hour '0' should  be '12' m = m < 10 ? '0'+m : m; h = h < 10 ? '0'+h : h; s = s < 10 ? '0'+s : s;           
          document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = day + " " + h + ":" + m + " " +    
          ampm; 
         let t = setTimeout(startTime, 500); 
        }

{{Html}}
<body onload="startTime()">
</body>
<div id="clock" class="ets-clock"></div>    
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Css For Ets-clock
    .ets-clock{
      align-items: center;
      margin-top: 12px;
      color: #fff;
      padding: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      margin-right: 15px;
      font-size: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      min-width: 100px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 180px;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #05274f;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      border-radius: 25px;
    }